# i'm not able to load the data to elastic search with template

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I can able to load the data into indices in ES with logstash but i've added template later data is not loading into indices . But indices are creating with no data . CAn u help me to resolve this issue .

```
template : 
PUT _template/template_name
{
    "index_patterns": [
      "index_patterns*"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "6"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
        "properties": {          
          "field3": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "field_name9": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "field_name8": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "field_name7": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "field_name6": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "field_name5": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "field_name4": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "field_name3": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "field_name2": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "field_name1" :{
            "type" : "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
      },
    "aliases" : { }
 }
```

logstash output : please find the below logstash output details

```
output {
elasticsearch {

   hosts => [""]

   index => "index_patterns-%{+dd-MM-YYYY}"
}
}
```

Kindly let me know if i'm missing any thing here .And i've tried without template  data is loading into indices .

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters template and template_overwrite as follows:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {

        template => "path to template e.g .json file"
        template_overwrite => true
        hosts => [""]
        index => "index_patterns-%{+dd-MM-YYYY}"
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the template and template_overwrite parameters but still i'm not able to load data into indices . 
If its  "mappings": =>  "logs :  i can able to load data to indices but mapping:=> "doc" i'm not able to load data to indices . Can u plz help me

Comment: try   "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
       "_all" : {"enabled" : true},

Comment: where can i need to add this code . can u please help me

Comment: In template you can mention this, is there any impact by keeping _type as logs. . You can check your records where you will get _type as logs because of this it is accepting data with that. Also you can check GET /_all/_mapping, in kibana

Comment: actullay what is the difference between logs and docs mapping type . does it make any query changes while doing on logs mapping type

Comment: no changes are required queries are done on index. No _type needed.